# Javafx HBox restrict to specific height

Tags: java, javafx

I have a HBox in my Javafx application  with below configuration

```
 HBox belowBox = new HBox(10);
 belowBox.getStyleClass().addAll("pane", "vbox");
 belowBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
 belowBox.getChildren().addAll( .... );
 belowBox.setMaxHeight(200);
 belowBox.setPrefHeight(200);
 belowBox.setFillHeight(false);
```

But still if I resize my application the HBox grows vertically. Is there a way to fix the height.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But this is the exact behavior of the HBox layout pane. If you read the [HBox documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html), you will see the following:

> HBox lays out its children in a single horizontal row...

And also:

> HBox will resize children (if resizable) to their preferred widths and uses its fillHeight property to determine whether to resize their heights to fill its own height or keep their heights to their preferred (fillHeight defaults to true)...

As said, if for some reason you set the [fillHeight](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#fillHeightProperty) property from HBox, you can make the nodes contained within to fill the vacant vertical space, But this will only occur for the nodes that are resizable. For more information about using the JavaFX layout panels, look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm). If I'm not mistaken, texts, geometric shapes and ImageView are not resizable objects.

Comment: Thank you @Loa. Let me check the documentation. Can you suggest any alternative solutions.

Comment: Your new question is a little vague. What exactly are you trying to do? What do you need? Maybe if you show me some desired result, I can guide you better. For example, what kind of GUI are you trying to achieve?